# Get http://<master-ip>:<nodeport>/metrics: context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-node-exporter

I made the Kubernetes cluster with 2 azure Ubuntu VMs and trying to monitor the cluster. For that, I have deployed node-exporter daemonSet, heapster, Prometheus and grafana. Configured the node-exporter as a target in Prometheus rules files. but I am getting `Get http://master-ip:30002/metrics: context deadline exceeded` error. I have also increased `scrape_interval` and `scrape_timeout` values in the Prometheus-rules file.

The following are the manifest files for the Prometheus-rules file and node-exporter daemonSet and service files.

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: node-exporter
  name: node-exporter
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-exporter
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --web.listen-address=<master-IP>:30002
        - --path.procfs=/host/proc
        - --path.sysfs=/host/sys
        - --path.rootfs=/host/root
        - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+)($|/)
        - --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(autofs|binfmt_misc|cgroup|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|mqueue|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|sysfs|tracefs)$
        image: quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:v0.18.1
        name: node-exporter
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 180Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 102m
            memory: 180Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /host/proc
          name: proc
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /host/sys
          name: sys
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /host/root
          mountPropagation: HostToContainer
          name: root
          readOnly: true
      - args:
        - --logtostderr
        - --secure-listen-address=[$(IP)]:9100
        - --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        - --upstream=http://<master-IP>:30002/
        env:
        - name: IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        image: quay.io/coreos/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.4.1
        name: kube-rbac-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9100
          hostPort: 9100
          name: https
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 40Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
      serviceAccountName: node-exporter
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /proc
        name: proc
      - hostPath:
          path: /sys
        name: sys
      - hostPath:
          path: /
        name: root
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: node-exporter
  name: node-exporter
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 9100
    targetPort: https
    nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    app: node-exporter
    
---prometheus-config-map.yaml-----
 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server-conf
  labels:
    name: prometheus-server-conf
  namespace: default
data:
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5m
      evaluation_interval: 3m

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node'
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['<master-IP>:30002']
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https
```

Can we take service as NodePort for Node-exporter daemonSet? if the answer NO, how could we configure in a prometheus-rules file as the target? Could anyone help me to understand the scenario? Are any suggestible links also fine?

Comment: Any error in the logs of the Daemonset?

Comment: Hii @ Arghya Sadhu. I have checked the logs of node-exporter daemonset. Actually my daemonset consists of two containers. first container(node-exporter) showing the logs as `Listening on localhost:9100" source="node_exporter.go:170" `. second container showing log as `Listening securely on [10.0.0.4]:9100 `. so, how could I configure node-exporter daemonset in prometheus rules file?

Comment: currently, following is error which i am getting in prometheus targets page: 
` Get http://localhost:9100/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9100: connect: connection refused `

Comment: Hello @gayathri,i have found older github [issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4419) with same issue as yours, can You confirm it's the same happening for You? Can you `curl http://10.0.0.107:9100/metrics`, but error occurs when You try to reach it from Prometheus? Could You try use solution from [there](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4419#issuecomment-408451914) and let me know if that help?

Comment: Thank you @jt97. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gayahtri confirmed in comments

> it worked for me. – gayathri

If you have same issue as mentioned in topic check out this [github issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4419)

specifically this [answer](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4419#issuecomment-408451914) added by @simonpasquier

> We have debugged it offline and the problem was the network.
>   Running the Prometheus container with "--network=host" solved the issue.